# Jest how to catch a React Native component that is unmounted / disappearing very fast

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ts-jest

Hi I have a loading spinner and I wanted to use jest testing to catch it so that I can verify if the loading spinner is loading on the screen. However, due to the loading spinner only appear for very small amount of time and then disappear, the Jest getByTestId is not able to catch that

```
    it('shows loading spinner', async () => {
      const { getByTestId } = renderPage();
      fireEvent.press(getByTestId('image-upload-button'));
      expect(getByTestId('modal-loading-icon')).toBeDefined();
    });
```

The logic of show the spinner is controlled by a state

```
    showSpinner(true);
    ...some functions
    showSpinner(false);
```

I expect the getByTestID will be able to catch the component ( spinner ) and not throwing null